# How do I make part of my Minecraft skin transparent?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want my Minecraft skin's head to be transparent entirely. If I try this with a skin editor, it shows as black in multiplayer. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I believe this is by design. You wouldn't want invisible people running around killing you and destroying your buildings if PvP was enabled. Similar to how Terraria won't let you create an all black character (clothes and all).

Comment: Good point, that

Comment: This is to prevent abuse as mentioned, though your hat can be transparent.

Comment: Well, as of 1.4, you could make invisibility potions. Just punch the victim to death if you want to be totally invisible or have a floating diamond sword :). I believe that mobs cannot see you unless you provoke them first, and that the most potent invisibility potion has a duration of six minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way of doing this, other than replacing the model for Steve with your own custom model (that has 'holes' in the right places).

Comment: How do I replace the model with my own, and will it be visible in multiplayer?

Comment: You will need to decompile and edit your copy of `minecraft.jar`, and it will not be visible in multiplayer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it invisible to my knowledge, however you can say, make it blend in with nighttime, and only go out after dark, or you can make it blend in with stone, and always stay underground. So other than camouflage you really can't be totally invisible, I'm not sure if the whole blackness thing was intentional at first, but after multiplayer was first implemented (Way back in...Creative, or Survival Test, I think), is probably when Notch made it an actual feature.

Answer (score 0):

In singleplayer, you can change the Steve/Alex texture or model in your resource pack and place that resource pack on your world. However, in multiplayer, this is impossible (you wouldn't want people to cheat, of course.)

Answer (score -1):

I made all my skins with photoshop, where it's pretty easy because TIFF saves information about "transparency" diffrent to many other formats that just fill in white once you save the file...
on photoshop you can just simply erase the area and save as TIFF... (transparency is shown with the grey/white sqares in the background layer)

EDIT:
ok I just checked my skins and its PNG! this will save your transparency information and just to show you how it looks I made an image of my enderman skin... if you want to get rid of the head... simply delete it... ^^

[image: endermanskin in photoshop, grey/white squares are transparent parts]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will just display as black again in multiplayer...

Comment: ok I'm sorry I was mislead by my own skin <.< it's actually really not possible, on my skin there was like 2 rows of pixel which actually didn't belong to the actual model (like headphones) so I could erase that <.< it's shown black eitherway sry :(

Comment: looks like its not possible then :(