# How do I make my skin transparent?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: http://pm1.narvii.com/5924/f6a58b5b0bd3f5c051bdfa703ca84c05c56f8acd_hq.jpg]

The guy in this picture has a transparent skin. Can anyone tell me how to get it?
From what I know, he is using Minecraft Version 1.9.

Comment: It's probably some sort of mod.

Comment: @TimmyJim @Frank @Oak Unfortunately, this isn't a dupe (or a mod). This was achieved not by editing a player's skin, but being invisible with team visibility on (so that you can see invisible people on your team). Just `/effect @p 14 9999` and some scoreboard/teams magic (the `seeFriendlyInvisibles` flag).

Comment: @aytimothy voted to reopen.  Post that as an answer once/if this reopens.

Answer (score 4):

## As used in the very old *Ghost Squadron* PvP map by *SethBling*...

You can create a ghostly effect by enabling visbility on invisible teammates.
The gist of this is simple:

- Create a team
- Assign yourself to that team
- Allow that team to see invisible teammates
- Become invisible

Essentially, enter the following commands:

```
/scoreboard team create team team
/scoreboard team join @p
/scoreborad team options team seeFriendlyInvisibles true
/effect @p minecraft:invisibility 9999 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a raw skin (without any custom stuff like the answer including a sethbling map) you cannot change the transparency of the base layer. You can change the transparency of the outer layers of the skin, though allowing some cool 3D effects. Just know that you won't be able to have a permanent transparent skin that is applied everywhere, such as servers or even other worlds.

Comment: That would be correct, if it was for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49072/how-do-i-make-part-of-my-minecraft-skin-transparent).

Comment: It was meant to be a more informative answer. It's the most you can do in pure vanilla that will work everywhere